# Why I can't use tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I use Ubuntu. When I try to install tkinter it throws error

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tkinter (from versions: none)

> ERROR: No matching distribution found for tkinter

I saw that this error is beacuse I already have tkinter, but when I try to import it there is another error

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkinter'

This happens also when I use capital T (Tkinter).

Comment: `tkinter` comes with the standard library, as long as you don't exclude it when installing Python.

Answer (score 0):

For installing tkinter in Ubuntu I use the command:

```
sudo apt install python3-tk
```